# searchin status field through gridview in yii

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I have used cgridview  like :-[image]

iif i am writing 0 in searching place of user status then it shows inactive record
but if i am writing inactive then no record found is coming.

In my table in status field 0=inactive and 1 = inactive (0 and 1) is there.

Comment: can you share your action where the AJAX request is going when you search?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CGridView's smart filters to search using 'Active' and 'Inactive'

```
$filter = array(
    '0' => 'Inactive',
    '1' => 'Active'
);
...
array(
    'name' => 'active',
    'value' => '($data->active)?"Active":"Inactive"',
    'filter' => $filter,
),
```

This will give you a dropdown to search from this field using the words 'Active' and 'Inactive'